# Can I change a window frame color?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-forms-designer

[Frame from Windows Forms](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qh9yK.jpg)

Is it possible to change a window frame color, **without using** a Panels and `FormBorderStyle: None`?

Comment: .NET has no methods for doing so. Although it is possible using low level DllImport and hooking up window painting, it's definitely not an easy task and results will differ on various windows versions.

Comment: @schnitz77 Thanks, I'll try to figure out with Dll's